# access struct data (matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

`a= struct('a1',{1,2,3},'a2',{4,5,6})`

how can Iget the value of 1;

I try to use a.a1{1} which return errors

```
>> a.a1{1}
??? Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more reference blocks is an
error.
```

How can I access 1? Thanks.

**Edit**
`A = struct{'a1',[1 2 3],'a2',[4 5 6]}`

How can I access 1. I use `A(1).a1` but I get `1 2 3`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to do this instead:

```
a(1).a1
```

The reason why is because the code you use to create your structure actually creates a 3-element structure array where the first array element contains `a1: 1` and `a2: 4`, the second array element contains `a1: 2` and `a2: 5`, and the third array element contains `a1: 3` and `a2: 6`.

When you use curly braces `{}` in a call to [STRUCT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) like you did, MATLAB assumes you are wanting to create a structure array in which you distribute the contents of the cells across the structure array elements. If you instead want to create a single 1-by-1 structure element where the fields contain cell arrays, you have to add an additional set of curly braces enclosing your cell arrays, like so:

```
a = struct('a1',{{1,2,3}},'a2',{{4,5,6}});
```

Then your original `a.a1{1}` will work.

**EDIT:**

If you create your structure using numeric arrays instead of cell arrays, like so:

```
A = struct('a1',[1 2 3],'a2',[4 5 6]);
```

Then you can access the value of 1 as follows:

```
A.a1(1)
```

For further information about working with structures in MATLAB, check out [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html).