# Matlab Array of structures: string not working

Tags: matlab, struct, cell, matlab-struct

I am reading an input from a file and importing it into my data to run in Matlab:

```
    parts = strread(tline,'%s','delimiter',';')       
    employee(i).name = parts(1);
    employee(i).salary= str2double(parts(2));
```

Then I try to print it out:

```
for i = 1:3
 fprintf('salary: %.2f\n',employee(i).salary);
 fprintf('employee name: %s\n',employee(i).name);
end
```

The salary prints with no problem. But the for the variable "name" it gives an error:

```
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.
fprintf('employee name: %s\n',employee(i).name);
```

I looked for some other examples:

[access struct data (matlab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044452/access-struct-data-matlab)

[How do I access structure fields dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882035/how-do-i-access-structure-fields-dynamically)

[Matlab Error: Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190168/matlab-error-function-is-not-defined-for-cell-inputs)

[How do i define a structure in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166438/how-do-i-define-a-structure-in-matlab)

But there is nothing to address this case, where only string is not working.

I have not explicitly declared the data as struct, i.e. inside the code there is nowhere the "struct" word is included, but Matlab apparently automatically understand it as an "Array of structures".

Any hints what might be missing here?

All comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: Given the error message I would imagine `employee(i).name` is a `cell` and not a `char`. What does `class(employee(i).name)` return?

Comment: I think `employee(i).name` is a cell. So see if you can do `str = employee(i).name{1}` and then use `str`.

Comment: it retuns: ans = 
cell

Comment: So...that means `parts` is probably a `cell` array and you'll want to [access data in a cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) when pulling data into `employee`

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - Thanks! It works. Anyway to avoid the need to use the str?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `employee(k).name` is a cell (check with `iscell(employee(1).name)`) and the format string `%s` doesn't know how to handle that.

The reason that it is a cell is because `strread` returns a cell array. To grab an element from the result (`parts`), you want to use `{}` indexing which returns a string rather than `()` which will return a cell.

```
employee(i).name = parts{1};
```

Comment: Thanks for the best answer!