# How can I open a struct in matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, struct, signal-processing

I do have a problem: I have a database from R that I converted in .mat and right now it is a 1x1 struct that I don't know how to open. I don't know what fields are in it, what I do know is that it is supposed to be a database with emg signals and some data from the pacients.

It looks like this:

basicDatase =

struct with fields:

```
x: [1×1 struct]
```

I used the function fieldnames but it doesn't seem to work.
Does anyone has any idea how to open and see what is inside?

Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks like the struct `basicDatase`  has a single field `x` which in turn is a struct. Try `basicDatase.x`

Comment: The following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044452/access-struct-data-matlab may also be of beneficial use for you too.